# Excel: How can I tile arrange charts that are on top of another

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I copy a chart several times in Excel, but when I paste them they all come one on top of the other, is there a command to arrange them in tiles.

Comment: After you paste just drag it to a new place or put the cursor in a different cell before you paste.

Comment: @DavidPostill I meant automatically

Comment: Select the charts you want to arrange  then Page layout > Align > Align Left /Right/Top/Bottom. Alternatively place the charts on a separate sheet [Display Multiple Charts On A Single Chart Sheet](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/display_multiple_charts_on_a_single_chart_sheet/)